# Non-generic intersections of Schubert varieties?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, intersection-theory, schubert-varieties

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, $B$ a Borel subgroup, $P$ a parabolic subgroup containing $B$, and $W$ the Weyl group. For $w \in W$, the Schubert variety $X_w^P$ is the closure of the Schubert cell $BwP$ in $G/P$. Now take three minimum length coset representatives $w_1, w_2, w_3 \in W/W_P$, where $W_P$ is the Weyl group of (the Levi subgroup) of $P$. Kleiman transversality guarantees an open set $U \subset G^3$, such that for $(g_1, g_2, g_3) \in U$, the intersection
\begin{equation}
g_1 X_{w_1}^P \cap g_2 X_{w_2}^P \cap g_3 X_{w_3}^P
\end{equation}
is proper (possibly empty). Let's call such an intersection for $(g_1, g_2, g_3) \in U$ a 'generic' intersection. Much attention has been given to when these generic intersections are non-empty (e.g., as parameterizations of the boundary of the saturated tensor cone in work of Belkale and Kumar.) Note that one can always find a triple $(g_1, g_2, g_3) \in G^3$ such that the intersection is non-empty.

My question starts when this 'generic' intersection is empty:

(1) Is there any understanding what these non-generic and non-empty (i.e., the non-proper and non-empty) intersections look like?

(2) Is there any understanding on the subset $G^3 \setminus U$ of $G$ that gives the non-proper, yet non-empty, intersections?

Certainly, this question needn't be framed in the context of Schubert varieties. But, perhaps this extra structure will help..... I realize asking what something 'looks like' is fairly open ended, but any thoughts on this are appreciated. Thanks for reading my questions!

Comment: I think the question is already pretty tough for two flags, much less three. You can always assume $g_1=1$ and $g_2 \in N(T)$ using the $B$-action (I'll also take $P=B$). Then $X_{w_1} \cap v X_{w_2} \neq \emptyset$ iff $[1,w_1] \cap v[1,w_2] \neq \emptyset$, and I don't see how to simplify the latter, purely combinatorial statement.

Comment: Let me add something that is obvious to Allen but might not be obvious to all readers: this is a closed union of B-orbits and hence a union of Schubert varieties.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Indeed, I have found these intersections nearly impossible to work with. But, it is really useful to know the difficulty is likely inherent.